# Shortcut to open a windows 8 application and do a functionality

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have a desktop application for my telephone which launches a call on selection+ctrl+left click on any proper telephone number that appears in my desktop, by opening that application. I wanted to do similar functionality for Windows 8 store application. Is that possible?

Siva

Answer (score 1):

I think the functionality you're after would be closest to a secondary tile.  Have a look [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Secondary-Tiles-Sample-edf2a178) for a sample.